# Likelihood of duplicates when generating 3 values and 'merging' them into one

Tags: probability

I'm currently generating a value like this: I generate one random letter. Then a 3 digit number and then another 3 digit number and place them into a string like this: `N344578`

How would I go about calculating the probability of a duplicate if I generate 1000 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if from a set $S$ with finite cardinality $n$ we randomly draw $k$ elements with replacement then: $$P(\text{no duplicate})=\frac{n}{n}\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-2}{n}\cdots\frac{n-k+1}{n}$$
(do you understand why?)

Of course we have also: $$P(\text{at least one duplicate})=1-P(\text{no duplicate})$$

You can apply this here.

Comment: I thought I understood but not really. Or at least I think I get the first part but you lost me in the second. I am interested in learning this tho!

Comment: Events can be complements of eachother, which is the case here: the negation of "no duplicate" is "at least one duplicate". If $A$ and $B$ are complements (i.e. the events cannot occur both and at least one of the events will certainly occur) then $1=P(A)+P(B)$ or equivalently $P(A)=1-P(B)$.

Comment: For the first part: after choosing a first element the probability on not drawing that element again at second draw is $\frac{n-1}{n}$. Then if indeed $2$ distinct elements are drawn the probability that the third will be different again is $\frac{n-2}{n}$. Et cetera.

Comment: yes it makes sense now I looked at it all wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are $26$ letters in the alphabet, and each digit can be from $0$ to $9$, so you have $26*10^6$ different combinations.
$\mathbb{P}$ (There is at least one duplicate with $n=1000$) = $1 - \mathbb{P}$ (There are no duplicates with $n=1000$) $=$ $1 - \dfrac{25999999\times25999998\times\cdots\times 25999001}{26000000^{999}} \approx 1 - 0.981 = 0.019$